# How to create a youtube lightbox in CMS Block. Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

can you help in on how to create a lightbox for youtube in CMS block of magento 2. I created something using lity but it will not work.

Thanks

Comment: Where you want to show this?

Comment: Hello Dhiren. I want it to show before the footer section.

Comment: Then you can do this via custom extension, add your phtml file using refrence of xml. And in phtml file you can do code what you like.